# Load blocking jQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a gallery viewer with a preload function.

The preload function is as follows:

```
$.preloadFullImages = function() {

    // Create array of images
    var set = [];
    $('.slide-item img').each(function() {
        var img = $(this).data('src');
        var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        $(this).remove();
        set.push([img,id]); 
    });

    // Set current image
    var current = 0;

    var iterate = function() {
        var current_src = set[current][0];         
        var current_id = set[current][1];
        var temp = '<img src="'+current_src+'" />';       
        var target = '#'+current_id;
        var targetImg = '#'+current_id+' img';

        // Load 'temp' image
        $(temp).bind('load', function() {
            // Show image
            $(target).append(temp);
            $(targetImg).show();
            $(this).remove();
        });

        if ( ++current < set.length ) iterate();
    };
    iterate();
};
```

On load of the page, images are loaded sequentially.

The problem is until all the images are loaded, the animation between images (prev and next arrows) is stunted and doesn't work correctly. I want the gallery viewer to transition smoothly between slides (images) even if not all images are loaded.

You can see a live demo here: http://www.davidclapp.net/portfolio

The issue is especially apparent on the iPhone (safari).

Is there a way to ensure the animation is smooth even whilst images are still loading?

Edit: I am using this plugin for CSS3 transitions - http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: You should probably preload all the animation images (sequences) before starting the animation.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mgleeson/kjrme1eo/ CALLBACK EXAMPLE

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mgleeson/pwt7ocaw/ Better example... Use something like this

Answer (score 0):

```
$.preloadFullImages = function(callback) {
```

...

```
    if ( ++current < set.length ) iterate();
    else if(callback) callback(); //check if callback exists, then call it.
};
iterate();
```

};

These two lines being the important part.

$.preloadFullImages = function(***callback***) {

if ( ++current < set.length ) iterate();
else ***callback();***

make a function to call the beginning of your animation, pass it to "preloadFullImages"

Comment: Could you give me an example. I am fairly new to jQuery.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mgleeson/sr7qA/#base this is without jQuery, something I made in the past that does what you're looking for

Comment: @ccdavies if you're looking for an example of how to use callbacks, I can show you that, but I don't have your DOM structure, so to use your code it wouldn't really be demonstrating properly what will happen

Comment: Thanks Mike. I am not sure I understand what animation I would place in the callback. Would you be willing to take a look at my script and explain to me? If so, whats your email address.

Comment: @ccdavies do you have a function that begins the animation/sequence of images? pass that as the callback

Comment: I have a function for 'next', 'prev' and 'thumb click', all of which contain animations.

Comment: @ccdavies basically what you need to be doing instead of what you are doing now is, preload all the images, do not attempt to start the animation (sequence) until all images in the sequence are loaded. This will fix your issues. (you can keep track of loaded images with a global variable, or you can stick your image sources in an array and pop them out as you load them, effectively creating a counter that takes care of itself)

Comment: There may be a large amount of images. I dont wish to make the user wait until all the images are loaded before being able to view the first few images. Is there no other way?